# Access to clipboard in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, image, clipboard

Can I get image from clipboard in Silverlight? How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Silverlight 5, access to clipboard information is **`limited to Unicode text access`**. This differs from the WPF implementation of Clipboard, which enables access to other specific types (for example, streams or images) or to data objects.

Details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.95).aspx

This may help you: [How to copy image of a chart from Silverlight application to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801130/how-to-copy-image-of-a-chart-from-silverlight-application-to-clipboard)